# Result from PHP markdown parser is string, not valid html

Tags: php, html, parsing, markdown, htmlpurifier

## Goal

I am trying to display links that a user has entered as either markdown or html into a description. The description is saved in a database, and then when its read, I'm trying to parse it to display as a link (rather than the literal markup/markdown).

## Problem

I'm using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to parse markdown that is stored in the database. When I run the string through the parser, the result on the page is not valid HTML, but instead the correct HTML simply inside a string.

```php
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href]');
$config->set('AutoFormat.Linkify', true);
$config->set('HTML.TargetBlank', true);
$config->set('HTML.TargetNoreferrer', true);

//My database result
$subrow['description'];

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
printf("<br />%s<br />", $purifier->purify($subrow['description'));
```

Currently the output is literally: `"A link <a href="https://url.com">my link</a>"`

[image]

*Screenshot from the chrome dev tools*

Comment: purify() is returning "A link <a href="https://url.com>my link</a>"? what's being fed to it?

Comment: Exactly the same, and done a type check to make sure it is a string

Comment: $test = "A link <a href=\"https://url.com>my link\">mylink</a>";printf('<br />%s<br />', $test); //this works for me... hrmm

Comment: @Ed Prince getType() returns string? Did you try printf("<br />%s<br />", (string)$purifier->purify($subrow['description']));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the encoding is changed inside of purifier... only a guess as I have never used it. I was able to mimic your results with the following:

```
$test = htmlentities("A link <a href=\"https://url.com/my link\">mylink</a>");
printf('<br />%s<br />', $test);
```

To get the valid markup back, I used [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
printf('<br />%s<br />', html_entity_decode($test));
```

Try

```
printf("<br />%s<br />", html_entity_decode($purifier->purify($subrow['description'])));
```

Does that help?